# Manipulate the value of a JSON and store in a new JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I currently have a JSON object `result` which looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "Score_A": -112.166458,
        "Score_B": 33.462795,
        "Rating": 3,
        "Team_Score": 5.01
    },
    {
        "Score_A": -112.11248,
        "Score_B": 33.510269,
        "Rating": 3,
        "Team_Score": 5.01
    },
    {
        "Score_A": -112.06501,
        "Score_B": 33.523769,
        "Rating": 2,
        "Team_Score": 5.02
    }
]
```

I want to store this in a variable `new_result` by removing the fields `Rating` and `Team_Score`. I also want to change the key for `Score_A` and `Score_B` to `User1_Score` and `User2_Score` respectively.

How can I do this?

Expected Result `new_result`:

```
[
    {
        "User1_Score": -112.166458,
        "User2_Score": 33.462795
    },
    {
        "User1_Score": -112.11248,
        "User2_Score": 33.510269
    },
    {
        "User1_Score": -112.06501,
        "User2_Score": 33.523769
    }
]
```

Note: The length of `result` is never constant.

Comment: `j.map(i => ({ User1_Score: i.Score_A, User2_Score: i.Score_B }))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`array.map`](https://mdn.io/array.map) function should do it:

```js
data = [
    {
        "Score_A": -112.166458,
        "Score_B": 33.462795,
        "Rating": 3,
        "Team_Score": 5.01
    },
    {
        "Score_A": -112.11248,
        "Score_B": 33.510269,
        "Rating": 3,
        "Team_Score": 5.01
    },
    {
        "Score_A": -112.06501,
        "Score_B": 33.523769,
        "Rating": 2,
        "Team_Score": 5.02
    }
]

result = data.map(item => ({
    user1_score: item.Score_A,
    user2_score: item.Score_B
}))

// Event more neat with new syntax:

result = data.map(({ Score_A, Score_B }) => ({
    user1_score: Score_A,
    user2_score: Score_B
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: *"Event more neat with new syntax"* — I dunno, just seems *more* verbose…

Comment: @deceze opinions... I could argue that i like it because it shows _what we need_ in the data for the result to happen. But whatever, I just show both options and op can choose!